# How to get the users with birth day that happen at this month?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, python-datetime

I am trying to get all the user with birth day of this month:

Did this but getting errors, Can any one help with what am i doing wrong?

```
birth_days = get_list_or_404(UserProfile, birthDate.month() == datetime.date.month())
```

I've tried many other things, but can't make it work...

thank you,
Erez

Comment: The Eclipse doesn't recognize birthDate as a field in the UserProfile, But it happen just when try the rest. It is a field in the model. From the python parser i am getting: "global name 'birthDate' is not defined" (the same thing that the eclipse tell me) but the field is in the model, something else is wrong in what i am doing.

Comment: @Erez the problem is that you have to specify a lookup. This is typically done via keywords in Django.Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/ how to specify lookups in django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems

1. `datetime.date.month()` does not exist, i think you mean `datetime.datetime.now().month`
2. You are not using the right criteria, again birtDay.month() does not exist, i think you should use

   birth_days = get_list_or_404(UserProfile, birthDate__month=datetime.datetime.now().month)

JFTR have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#month